# How can I show a Slot/Fill in the block editor

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I am trying to render a Slot/Fill using [`createSlotFill`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/slot-fill/) from `@wordpress/components`.

I have created a test extension using `@wordpress/create-block` and I have edited the `Edit` component like so:

```js
const { Fill, Slot } = createSlotFill( 'MyFill' );
const MyFillItem = () => <Fill>My item in the editor</Fill>;

export default function Edit() {
    return (
        <p { ...useBlockProps() }>
            <Slot />
            { __( 'Fill Test – hello from the editor!', 'fill-test' ) }
        </p>
    );
}
```

however when rendering in the editor it does not show my `MyFillItem`. Even if I explicitly render `MyFillItem` it does not show up.

Am I missing any steps?

Answer (score 2):

By wrapping everything in a `<SlotFillProvider>` and rendering `MyTestFill` it works, here is the code:

```js
const { Fill, Slot } = createSlotFill( 'MyFill' );
const TestFill = () => <Fill>My item in the editor</Fill>;

export default function Edit() {
    return (
        <p { ...useBlockProps() }>
            <SlotFillProvider>
                <Slot />
                { __( 'Fill Test – hello from the editor!', 'fill-test' ) }
                <TestFill />
            </SlotFillProvider>
        </p>
    );
}
```